# Can't bind mounts Docker volume with Nextjs

Tags: docker, next.js

I have a project with api and client services. Here is the structure

[image]

My frontend is Nextjs and I am trying to test the live coding changes with Docker so I am trying to mount my client folder with my container. I can't bind it to only the src folder like in React because the structure of Nextjs is different

```
docker run --rm --name myclient -p 3000:3000 -v $(pwd):/app client
```

The error I am having:

```
sh: 1: next: not found
```

But when I bind it to a specific folder it will work. i.e: the pages folder but then only codes in that folder are updated.

```
docker run --rm --name myclient -p 3000:3000 -v $(pwd)/pages:/app/pages client
```

My client's docker file:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

server's dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

Other containers: mongodb and api server

```
docker run --rm --name mongodb --network easyhome-net mongo
docker run --rm --name myserver --network easyhome-net -p 5000:5000 server
```

Comment: When you bind /app you're overwriting the content of the app directory built within the docker build process.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to watch my code changes so if this was React I could have bind it to only the /src folder not everything like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution myself. We need to bind the node_modules from our container to overwrite the possible node_modules that will be bind from our host machine.

Because this volume: `-v $(pwd):/app` will bind everything from our local host to the container.

Should be like this:

```
docker run --rm --name myclient -p 3000:3000 -v $(pwd):/app -v /app/node_modules client
```

The anonymous volume `-v /app/node_modules` has longer url path than the bind mount `-v $(pwd):/app` therefore it has higher priority